# Как сделать поле nullable не используя change в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, миграция

Как через миграции сделать уже существующее поле nullable, после выполнить определённые действия и убрать nullable, не используя ->change().

p.s Нет doctarina/dba для моей версии php, по этому ищу пути в обход.

Comment: DB::raw('ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN field nullable(true)');

не сработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `requisites` CHANGE `kpp` `kpp` VARCHAR(255) NULL'); // сделать поле nullabel

DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `requisites` CHANGE `kpp` `kpp` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;'); // отменить nullable
```

p.s Хоть он в laravel отображает весь запрос как ошибку, но этот способ работает безотказно. Нашёл я его просто ковыряюсь в phpMyAdmin